# Explanation of quiver arrow scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good afternoon,

I have been trying to understand the documentation of the matplotlib quiver function. And my eyes are officially bleeding.

I have attempted to play with the keyword arguments in my simple example below in order to understand how to change the appearance of my arrows, but half of the keyword arguments have no affect and the other half cause errors to be thrown. See below the code for some specific questions.

```
# ODE for falling object
def field(t, v):
    v_dot = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * v
    return v_dot

# gamma is the coefficient for air resistance
gamma = 0.392
mass = 3.2

x = np.linspace(0,50, 11) # time from zero to 50 inclusive
y = np.linspace(0,100, 11)# initial velocities from 0 to 100 inclusive

# meshgrid creates two arrays of shape(len(y), len(x))
# by pairing the values of these two arrays, we create a set
# of ordered pairs that give our coordinates for the location
# of the quiver arrows we wish to plot.
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# We know slope is v' = f(t, v), so we can use trig to get
# to the x and y components of our quiver arrow vectors
theta = np.arctan(field(X, Y))
U = np.cos(theta)
V = np.sin(theta)

plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)

plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Functional Questions**
How do I change the width or length of the arrows (supposing that I want to change them all uniformly)?

How do I change length AND/OR width of the arrows (supposing I want them to shrink or grow based on the y (velocity) values)?

What does the "angles" argument do? I thought that the angles were determined by the vector component arguments U and V...

What about the argument "units"? What does this argument do functionally?

If I choose `units='width'` what width are we referring to here? The documentation says the width of the axis, but that makes no sense to me... And when I choose `units='y'` nothing changes in the appearance of my graph. So what is the point of this argument?

As you can see, I have a lot of questions, and the documentation here is quite poor in my opinion. Perhaps it is understandable by someone with more advanced knowledge that I do not have.

Any links to good tutorials for beginners would be great. None of the ones I have found do much with the keyword arguments, and those that do are too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: Stackoverflow is rather meant to be used for specific questions, not for collecting links to tutorials. So do you have a particular problem you want to solve?

Comment: I asked some very specific questions in addition to my query for links and tutorials. You might re-read the question to find them.

Comment: I don't know, it sounds like you want someone to talk you through [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) which should answer most of those questions. The above was mainly meant as a hint for you to consider, but feel free to ignore it or come back to it if noone has answered this question in 2 weeks or so.